# ios selected cell view in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to use a `UITableView`.  In it I have a feature to swipe left and set an alarm.  All this functionality is working except when I select a cell, which takes me to another view and go back.  The swipe indicator is gone.  I set the right swipe Icon by putting a view behind the text and setting the background image.  When you swipe left a number appears (which is really just behind the views that shows the time the reminder will set.  The problem is that a selected cell seems to remove the view with the background image.  This is the only problem with this setup.

```
 self.panView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "tableSwipe.png")!)
```

[image]
I would like the green swipe indicator to always be available.
[image]

Comment: What have you already tried to solve this problem for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a cell is selected, a `selectedBackgroundView` is added to its view hierarchy.  This view appears above the `backgroundView`.

Your swipe indicator isn't visible in the selected cell, because it appears underneath the opaque `selectedBackgroundView`.